# XOR between two strings of bits

Tags: boolean, logic, computer-science, bit, xor

Is this always true?

We have two strings of bits s1 and s2, the XOR value between them is S, imagine we change n bits in s1 (let's call it s1' now), then let's call S' the XOR value between s1' and s2, is it true S is equal to S' but n bits?

```
s1 = 100001;
s2 = 100011;
S =  000010;
```

Let's change 2 bits in s1 so now

```
s1' = 100111;
S'  = 000100;
```

S and S' differ only for 2 bits. But does this work always? I don't know much about XOR's properties and basic computer science in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes XOR doesn't have any carry. So the number of bits you change in one of the inputs will be the number of output bits changed.

```
INPUT   OUTPUT
A   B   A XOR B
0   0   0
0   1   1
1   0   1
1   1   0
```